# factory pattern is it okay to use it this way?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependencies, factory

In my program, some objects need other objects (dependency), and I'm using Factory as my creational pattern.

Now, how do I solve a simple dependency problem?

This is an example of what I'm doing to solve my problem. I want to know if sending the needed objects to the Create method is not something horribly wrong.

```
//AbstractBackground
// - SpecialBackground
// - ImageBackground
// - NormalBackground
class Screen{
    List<AbstractBackground> list;
    Cursor cursor;
    ContentManager content;

    public void load(string[] backgroundTypes){
        //is this okay? --------------->
        AbstractBackground background = BackgroundFactory.Create(backgroundTypes[0], cursor, content);
        list.add(background);
    }
}

class BackgroundFactory{
    static public AbstractBackground Create(string type, Cursor cursor, ContentManager content){

        if( type.Equals("special") ){
            return new SpecialBackground(cursor, content);
        }

        if( type.Equals("image") ){
            return new ImageBackground(content);
        }

        if( type.Equals("normal") ){
            return new NormalBackground();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: More suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why would it be wrong? It's not.

Comment: I wanted to know that, since I don't have that much of experience with factory patterns in real life examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer, it looks good. If you think of this abstractly, you are injecting the objects into the constructor through the create method. Nothing wrong with this technique, and is something that I recommend.

Later, if you need to change the implementation, you can create other create methods as needed without breaking anything.

Answer (score 5):

It is functional, however, it might get cumbersome if more types are added.
According to my personal preferences for the simple factory the implementation would be:

```
enum BackgroundFactoryType
{
  Special,
  Image,
  Normal,
}

static class BackgroundFactory{

  static Dictionary<BackgroundFactoryType, Func<Cursor, ContentManager, AbstractBackground>> constructors;

  static BackgroundFactory()
  {
    //initialize the constructor funcs
    constructors = new Dictionary<BackgroundFactoryType, Func<Cursor, ContentManager, AbstractBackground>>();
    constructors.Add(BackgroundFactoryType.Special, (cursor, content) => new SpecialBackground(cursor, content));
    constructors.Add(BackgroundFactoryType.Image, (_, content) => new ImageBackground(content));
    constructors.Add(BackgroundFactoryType.Normal, (_, __) => new NormalBackground());
  }

  static public AbstractBackground Create(BackgroundFactoryType type, Cursor cursor, ContentManager content)
  {
    if (!constructors.ContainsKey(type))
      throw new ArgumentException("the type is bogus");

    return constructors[type](cursor, content);
  }
}
```

or you could simply do:

```
static class BackgroundFactory{

  static public AbstractBackground Create(BackgroundFactoryType type, Cursor cursor, ContentManager content)
  {
    switch (type)
    {
      case BackgroundFactoryType.Special:
        return new SpecialBackground(cursor, content);
      case BackgroundFactoryType.Image:
        return new ImageBackground(content);
      case BackgroundFactoryType.Normal:
        return new NormalBackground();
      default:
        throw new ArgumentException("the type is bogus");
    }
  }
}
```

One nice side-effect of this approach, is that it takes just a little work to make this thing configuration driven instead of hard coded.

Comment: Since `BackgroundFactory` has only static members should not it be marked as `static`?

Comment: Yes, it should, and the constructors dictionary too :)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing so ugly in your code, except the fact that if your dependency tree grow the factory method you create will became complex.
In order to factorize types with various and articulated dependencies you probably better choose an `IoC` based factory. By registering the dependency in the container you will have automatic injected constructors with the required dependencies.

Comment: May I ask for an example? I've encountered many examples but some just seem way too complex to solve something simple or examples that I have no idea if it solves what I want to do.

Comment: @user658091 if your architecture is supposed to stay simple, stay. As said there is nothing wrong at the moment with your code.